# Jquery form submit not working for file upload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Please refer this fiddle [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxd65/)

Here the `$('#photoform').serialize();` not return the form field. This problem occurs only for the file field.

How to get this file field values

Answer (score 0):

A file cannot be uploaded using AJAX because you cannot access the contents of a file stored on the client computer and send it in the request using javascript.

An alternative to do this is to use a hidden iframe. [This plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) can help you [doing that](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) (read [this little tutorial](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/jquery-form-plugin-and-php-file-uploads/) for that plugin, too).

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/): "*Data from file select elements is not serialized.*"